# Ionic: Dropdown bug inside iframe ios

Tags: ios, iframe, ionic-framework

I am developing an app for a store.I'm doing it using Ionic/Cordova but I have a weird bug in ios: When the page has a dropdown I can't select the option. 
Example:
[image: iframe inside ionic app]

Do you have any answer to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Change this to false to return accessory bar

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

Credits: [Ionic Forum - Select dropdown issue on ios](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/select-dropdown-issue-on-ios/5573/4)

Comment: I had forgotten that I had previously hidden the keyboard accessories, so this issue was giving me a lot of grief. Fortunately this answer reminded me that I needed to turn the accessories back on!